# Search pattern occurrence in log file only where other pattern occur

Tags: regex, shell, scripting, grep, ksh

Now I use this command to obtain the number of occurrences of a pattern in the log file.

```
cat filename.log | grep -c 'myPattern'
```

The problem is I want to know only the occurrences between two or three hours. In fact, concat two pattern recognitions, one to select the range of text to apply the second pattern recognition.

I try with something like this but does not work:

```
cat filename.log | grep -c 'myPattern' | grep {21:,22:,23:}
```

I have never understood how the flux goes when you concat two or more pipes.

Log file example:

```
20130305-22:31:36 0 0000 pcxvx28p script.ksh               1.10     FIN
20130305-22:36:36 0 0000 pcxvx28p script.ksh               1.10     DEBUT
20130305-22:31:36 0 0000 pcxvx28p script.ksh               1.10     OPERACION BUSQUEDA
20130305-22:36:36 0 0000 pcxvx28p script.ksh               1.10     numero xxx20012
```

NOTE: I use **KornShell (ksh)** 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how does your logfile look like? paste some example. also, you don't need that `cat`

Comment: I add 3 lines of the logfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
grep -c '^20130305-2[1-3].*myPattern' your.log
```

date should be added into the pattern too, because your log could have more than one day's data.

the above line will count matched entries during `21:00 -23:59:59`

Comment: Your answer works fine but i need to accurate more to make the script more general. grep -c '-2[1-3].:*myPattern' your.log  --> I want to do something like this, but grep's thowing an error message. I want to add in the search pattern the '-' before and the ':' after.

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez sorry, I didn't understand what you are talking about... `I want to add in the search pattern the '-' before and the ':' after.` can you understand yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The -c option should not be used since it gives the number of matching lines instead of the matching line text

```
grep 'myPattern' filename.log | grep '\(21:\)\|\(22:\)\|\(23:\)'
```

Comment: I try your command but doesn't work for me. After that i try 'cat filename.log' | grep '\(21:\)\|\(22:\)\|\(23:\)' ' to display only the lines which have the patterns 21: 22: or 23: but doesn't work too.

Comment: It is working for me. Note the `\\` before each bracket that I have used.

Comment: But, how to know the number of occurrences, sorry i forget to write i use Korn shell. And I obtain nothing as result.

Comment: I am working on bash, so can't say about korn.. To get the count, use the `-c` option with the second `grep` instead of the first.